# Why I am getting PACKAGE-LOCKED-ERROR when trying to use function in alexandria package?

Tags: common-lisp

I don't understand why this is throwing an error at all.  Please explain why this would be and how I can clear this unexpected blockage.  Thanks.

```
CL-USER> (alexandria::starts-with-subseg "cat" "catdog")
; Debugger entered on #<PACKAGE-LOCKED-ERROR "interning ~A" {10059DE253}>

Lock on package ALEXANDRIA.1.0.0 violated when
interning STARTS-WITH-SUBSEG while in package COMMON-LISP-USER.
```

(edit) just realized it's a bad function name. But still, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Alexandria hadn't put a package lock, you would see a more common error message:

```
The function ALEXANDIRA::BAD-FN-NAME is undefined.
```

But they put a lock:

```
(defpackage :alexandria
  (:nicknames :alexandria.1.0.0 :alexandria-1)
  (:use :cl)
  #+sb-package-locks
  (:lock t)
  …
```

Now you first saw this lock error, but look further and see the available restarts:

```
Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Ignore the package lock.
 1: [IGNORE-ALL] Ignore all package locks in the context of this operation.
 2: [UNLOCK-PACKAGE] Unlock the package.
 3: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 4: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 5: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1007D29B63}>)
```

Choose the 0 to ignore the lock, and you'll now stumble on the "undefined function" error.

But now, go back to your REPL, and try to autocomplete the bad function name: you can O_o This is not so great, actually. When you call a function, or simply try to evaluate a symbol with the Lisp interpreter, your Lisp first "interns" (creates) this symbol into the corresponding package. It is now "bound" and it will stay around unless you "unbind" it with `makunbound`.

Alexandria developers took a defensive approach, and that's good because Alexandria is an important piece of the CL ecosystem. You don't want to change its bindings by error. Imagine doing, by inadvertance…

```lisp
(defun alexandria:starts-with-subseq () 
   :AHAHAH)
```

But you can't, you get the package lock error! Thank you, Alexandria.

```
Lock on package ALEXANDRIA violated when
setting fdefinition of STARTS-WITH-SUBSEQ while in package CL-USER
```

you can of course carry on with the restart, but you've been warned.

---

http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Package-Locks

ps: you only need 1 colon when calling a function: `alexandria:foo` and not `::`.